# sending UISlider's moving value from one device to another device using GameKit

Tags: ios, gamekit

I'm looking for example code for sending UISlider's moving value from one device to another device using Bluetooth. I'm able to send text as well as image from one device to another device. but now, I want to do send slider value. if i move slider than same position also move in another device..

Comment: just convert the value to text and then transfer it to the other device

Comment: if i move slider than same position also move in another device..

Comment: I don't see a problem. On the second device you convert the text back into a float which you use to set the value of the slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have a method that turns the slider's value into an NSNumber or NSString and then sends it in the same way.

So you would have:

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderMoved:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

then in your sliderMoved:

```
-(void)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)slider {
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)slider.value];
    // or
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",(int)slider.value];
    //Then you would want to send it to the other device.
}
```

You can also not cast them as integers if you want the full float values of the slider.

in that case, you would instead use:

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:slider.value];
// or
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",slider.value];
```

After you recieve this value on the other device, convert it back to a float and set that device's slider value:

```
float f = [newValue floatValue];
[slider setValue:f animated:YES/NO];
```

Comment: hi,how can i send UIButton's moving value(Position) from one device to another device

Comment: You would do basically the same thing. Store the position in some format that can be sent (eg [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i,%i",(int)pos.x,(int)pos.y]) and then send it and parse it on the other device.